# Mongodb Python: How to use $push overwrites existing value rather than adds to the end of an array within a document

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a document like this

> { "_id" : 23, "local_id" : 1234, "global_id" : [ "P123", "P345" ] }

If I want to `$push` new value to the array has the key “global_id” then I can do this

```
collection.update_one({‘local_id’: l_pid}, {’$push’: {‘global_id’: "P678"}})
```

and the document looks sth like this , for example : (push P678 to the array)

> { “_id” : 23, “local_id” : 1234, “global_id” : [ “P123”, “P345”,
> “P678” ] }

But next time when the same key of “global_id” comes in it keeps appending to the end of array like : (this time the same P678 comes in)

> { “_id” : 23, “local_id” : 1234, “global_id” : [ “P123”, “P345”,
> “P678” , “P678”] }

I want it to overwrite to existing value, and the array has to have unique value, the value can’t be the same.

How can I do it?
Thanks

Comment: Rather than `"$push"` you could use [`"$addToSet"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/).

Answer (score 1):

Base on @rickhg12hs answer, use `$addToSet` solve my issue

```
collection.update_one({‘local_id’: l_pid}, {’$addToSet’: {‘global_id’: "P678"}})
```